# Can the motion tracking of Google's Tango project be used in Qt Apps for Android?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, google-project-tango, motion-detection

Is it possible to use the C-API of [Google's Tango Library](https://developers.google.com/tango/) outside Android Studio? I want to build a Qt application for Android (using Qt-Creator) and use the motion tracking of Google's Tango project. How would I have to set up such a project?

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio is just an IDE, keeping in mind that the tango library also needs the NDK, I assume that the Studio requirement is more for the Android SDK part, because you cannot target Android without it.

The tango library appears to be a C library, hence the NDK requirement. That means you can directly use it from C++, and as such, using Qt Creator as an IDE.

There is also a Java binding for the library, which you can use from Qt via the `QAndroidJniObject` class, but at any rate, it would be easier and more efficient to use the native C API directly.

There shouldn't be anything fancy you need to do to set up a project, just link the tango libraries to a regular Qt project, you can use the Add Library wizard that comes with Qt Creator.